# Switch GNU Screen windows with F-keys on PuTTy

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, gnu-screen

I'm trying to use the f-keys to switch windows on GNU Screen/PuTTy, but I can't get it to work.

This is my current .screenrc:

```
bindkey -k k1 select 1
bindkey -k k2 select 2
bindkey -k k3 select 3
(...)
```

Changing the PuTTy keyboard options to "XTerm R6" did not work. I also don't know how discover what keycode is being received by screen when I press a key on Putty.

Edit:

Problem solved! Turns out I had to close and reopen the screen session for the configuration to take effect (I was detaching and reattaching).

My current .screenrc is:

```
bindkey "\033OP" select 0
bindkey "\033OQ" select 1
bindkey "\033OR" select 2
bindkey "\033OS" select 3
bindkey "\033[15~" select 4
bindkey "\033[16~" select 5
bindkey "\033[17~" select 6
bindkey "\033[18~" select 7
bindkey "\033[19~" select 8
```

And PuTTy is set to VT100+.

Comment: Do you want to change the TTY? Like you do with ctrl+alt+fn?

Comment: @criziot No, I want to change windows inside a GNU Screen session

Comment: Sorry. I miss the "screen" part. Maybe [this](http://superuser.com/questions/248517/show-keys-pressed-in-linux) can help.

Comment: That helped (ctrl-v), but I still cant get it to work. I also tried the instructions [here](http://superuser.com/questions/231647/how-do-i-get-the-f1-f12-keys-to-switch-screens-in-gnu-screen-in-cygwin-when-conn?rq=1) with no success.

Comment: Nice you found a solution. But don't put it the in the Question. Answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to figure out what your F1 key produce.  I used emacs to do that.

1. Login your system remotely with putty
2. Run screen, and then
3. run `emacs -nw`
4. switch to `*scratch*` buffer (or whatever)
5. Hit `C-q F1` (`C-q` is `quoted-insert` and this will puts exact byte you get from `F1` key)
6. Copy that string to your .screenrc

My system, putty on windows accessing Debian unstable amd64 with screen 4.1.0~201203, got `^[[11~`, so I put

```
bindkey "^[[11~" select 1
```

in my .screenrc and it seems to work.

Hope this helps.